# Correct way to use functions from files within a subpackage

Tags: python, module, package

Suppose I have the following directory structure for a module in python:

```
mypackage
    __init__.py
    module_a.py
    module_b.py
    subpackage
        __init__.py
        module_c.py
        module_d.py
        module_e.py
```

In `module_c.py` I want to access functions from `module_d.py` and `module_e.py`, but for one reason or another I need to access them with the syntax `subpackage.module_d.function_0()`. The issue is that, if I try doing:

```py
from mypackage import subpackage

subpackage.module_d.function_0()
```

It does not find `subpackage.module_d`

One way I noticed that works is if, within `subpackage.__init__.py` I do:

```py
from subpackage import module_d
from subpackage import module_e
```

But I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. Is it correct, or is there any alternative way?

Comment: Modules are not, in general, attributes of their containing package.  Your imports in `__init__.py` *create* those module-valued attributes.

Comment: Despite identical syntax, `import module.subpackage` uses a dotted module name, not an attribute lookup like `subpackage.module_d.function_0()` does. (Compare `print(ast.dump(ast.parse("import foo.bar").body[0], indent=4))` and `print(ast.dump(ast.parse("foo.bar.baz()").body[0], indent=4))`.)